# VS Code scss Хост-процесс для расширений неожиданно завершил работу

Tags: visual-studio-code, отладка, scss

Как решить проблемы с завершением работы редактора.
Это происходит когда открываю проект на vs code. При условии если в проекте есть папка scss (даже если она с пустыми файлами). То редактор сразу завершает работу. Если папку убрать, запустить редактор и папку вернуть все работает.
Если создать новую папку и файлами и работать все ок, но как только перезагружаешь редактор, снова сбой. Приходиться вытаскивать папку, запускать проект и после полной загрузки плагинов, добавлять папку обратно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки стоят такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Система MacOs catalina
Плагины: Live Sass Compiler, Sass,  SCSS Formatter

Comment: та же самая проблема.есть решение??

Comment: Обновление VS Code. У меня тоже такая проблема. Жду след. обновление. Пусть девелоперы починить этот баг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift+Ctrl+P -> Перезагрузить с отключенными расширениями
Потом Shift+Ctrl+P -> Включить все расширение

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).